# What does this.Validate() do? Called from BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click put in by VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

By default, Visual Studio put this code in my BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click method.

```
this.Validate();
this.detimpBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.rDataSet);
```

What does `this.Validate()` do and how does it work?  When I set a breakpoint, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: See [ContainerControl.Validate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf8t2at(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case, it basically fires the `Validating` and `Validated` events (in that order) on `this`'s child controls

Comment: Thank you!  You solved the mystery.